# console.log to JSON format and pass to controller -jquery /MVC

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have a list of table values in view and want to pass this data to controller using jQuery on button click event. I get my list of values as following :

```
$('#BtnSave').click(function () {
   var timsheetDetail = [];

   $("#timetable tr").each(function () {
       var taskId = $(this).find('input[id$=testTaskId]');
       var Day1 = $(this).find('input[id$=Day1]');
       var Day2 = $(this).find('input[id$=Day2]');
       var Day3 = $(this).find('input[id$=Day3]');
       var Day4 = $(this).find('input[id$=Day4]');
       var Day5 = $(this).find('input[id$=Day5]');
       var Day6 = $(this).find('input[id$=Day6]');
       var Day7 = $(this).find('input[id$=Day7]');

       if (typeof taskId.val() === "undefined") {
       }
       else {                  
           timesheetDetail.push({
               TaskId: taskId.val(), 
               Day1: day1.val(),
               Day2: day2.val(),
               Day3: day3.val(), 
               Day4: day4.val(), 
               Day5: day5.val(), 
               Day6: day6.val(), 
               Day7: day7.val()
           });
           console.log("Task ID: " + taskId.val());
           console.log("Day 1: " + Day1.val());
           console.log("Day 2: " + Day2.val());
           console.log("Day 3: " + Day3.val());
           console.log("Day 4: " + Day4.val());
           console.log("Day 5: " + Day5.val());
           console.log("Day 6: " + Day6.val());
           console.log("Day 7: " + Day7.val());                   
       }             
   });
   var saveTimesheet = $.ajax({
       url: "/Timesheet/SaveTimesheet",
       data: JSON.stringify(timesheetDetail),
       contentType: "application/json",
       type: "POST"
   });          

});
```

But I am not able to call event in controller? Also how can I get this list of values in controller?

Comment: Are you trying within `$(document).ready()` function?

Comment: Yes @Vishnu I tried within $(document).ready()

Comment: What does `not able to call event in controller` mean? Suggest you tag this with appropriate server framework you are using

Comment: the controller event not called. but now it goes to controller. But I try as follow :  var JSONString = {
                           "TaskId" : taskId.val(),  Day1: Day1.val(),
                           Day2: Day2.val(),  Day2: Day3.val(),
                           Day2: Day4.val(),  Day2: Day5.val(),
                           Day6: Day6.val(),  Day7: Day7.val()
                   }; testobj.push(JSONString);
                   console.log(testobj); in console "[object Object]""[object Object]""[object Object]" i get